# Creating extra presentation properties for ItemsSource items

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have an ObservableCollection of items bound to a listbox as the ItemsSource.

Some of these items are also located in another collection on the same ViewModel (call it CollectionTwo).

I want to be able to take the count of the item in Collection2 and display it for the respective item in CollectionOne. When CollectionTwo properties change (ie the Count), it must also be reflected back to CollectionOne.

I would guess the best way to do this in MVVM is to wrap items in CollectionOne with a viewmodel class with an extra Count property on it. Can someone point me to a good example of this? Or perhaps another method to tackle this problem that won't hugely weigh down my ItemsSource performance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inheritance to create a custom collection along these lines...

```
public class MyCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // implementation goes here...
    //
    private int _myCount;
    public int MyCount
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _myCount; }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            if (value != _myCount)
            {
                _myCount = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyCount");
            }
        }
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var handler = System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref PropertyChanged, null, null);
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

This is a class that wraps an Observable Collection and puts a custom property in it.  The property participates in change notification, but that depends upon your design.

To wire it up, you can do something like this...

```
    public MyCollection<string> Collection1 { get; set; }
    public MyCollection<string> Collection2 { get; set; } 
    public void Initialise()
    {
        Collection1 = new MyCollection<string> { MyCount = 0 };
        Collection2 = new MyCollection<string> { MyCount = 0 };
        Collection2.CollectionChanged += (s, a) =>
            {
                // do something here
            };
    }
```

You can also do something like...

```
Collection1.PropertyChanged += // your delegate goes here
```

Comment: GREAT! Thanks for the concise solution. Simple enough!

Comment: Hi again @GarryVass, I'm only just now implementing this new wrapped ObservableCollection, but I don't think it *quite* answers my question. This is not appending each item in the collection with MyCount property, correct? Rather, it is adding *one* MyCount property to the entire Collection1 or Collection2? So the only way to add an additional property to each item in the collection would be to define an additional class that wrapps the properties of the items, adds an additional "view-state" property, which I then wrap in a regular ObservableCollection?

Comment: Yes, if you needed an additional property appended to EACH ITEM in the collection.  The above framework should be helpful nonetheless, and let me know if you need an update